# TypeScript config file error: cannot find type definition file for 'android'

Tags: typescript, react-native, tsconfig

Hi I am programming a react native app, and when I run the code it gives me this error:

```
cannot find type definition file for 'android'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'android
```

I have no idea what this error means and what it does.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated

Comment: you need to install the types for this package. you can try `npm i --save-dev @types/android`

Comment: Error: error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types%2fandroid: Not found".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/app/Frontend/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.